# How do I extract button and action from PDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf

In my project I need to get the action behind a button on a PDF in python. PDFMiner, PyPDF etc. all talk about extracting text from pdf. How do we extract buttons and other controls from a PDF and actions behind them.

Answer (score 1):

A button is a special kind of widget in PDF parlance. All widgets in a page can be extracted using PyMuPDF and the function [Page.widgets()](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page/#Page.widgets), which returns a generator so you can loop over all the widgets on a page using something like:

```py
import fitz # The package you need to install is actually called pymupdf


# Open the PDF
doc = fitz.open('your.pdf')
# Whichever page holds the buttons
page_number = 1 
page = doc[page_number]

# Loop over all the widgets on this page and print their type
for w in page.widgets():
    print(f"Widget has the type {w.field_type_string}")
    # Do whatever else you want to do with the widget
```

Once you found the button, you may be able to extract the action behind it by reading its `script` attribute.

However, I have been trying the same exact thing and from the documentation linked above it sounds like it should work, but in the PDF I was looking at the button's `script` attribute was still `None`. So if this works for you or if you have found another way to extract the action, please share!

Comment: I am also not having much luck with using `page.widgets()`. I keep getting `ValueError: orphaned object: parent is None`. I have tried a few different PDFs...